# Debian - Correctly compile libdrm and Mesa

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, kali-linux

Post updated, the new question is now on my "own" answer down here.

I think about playing Team Fortress 2 on Kali Linux (a Debian Wheezy stable distribution with customized Debian Sid kernel) since a long time now, but couldn't because of the following graphical glitches:

- Bad dark textures
- Very low FPS
- Low brightness
- Green texture on training video

The solution after a lot of research was to compile a newer version of Mesa over 8.0.5. As today I found a very promising guide that was planned for Fedora, but someone managed to make it so in Debian:

http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/Building/   ->   Official Guide

https://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2013/03/msg00014.html   ->   Wheezy way

But I'm now stuck at the make process, because no nouveau.h could be found on the system.
So the question is:

Did anyone managed to overcome this nouveau.h missing file problem, then complete the full building or installation process ?

I have the same problem than: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827233/installing-mesa-10-on-debian, but since I use Mesa 9.0.3, I meet that problem instead of the libdrm-intel's one.

I have tried:

- Checking the missing file with updatedb + locate
- Checking if the file exists in any dependencies or packages in the repository
- Compile with Mesa 10.2.8, 10.1.6, 10.0.5, 9.2.5, 9.1.7 and 9.0.3

PS: It would be much better to have the latest Mesa 10.2.8, but I really don't want to compile any other intel, radeon or nouveau driver to make it work. If there is a way to make it so, I would switch to 10.2.8 immediately, knowing that it supports OpenGL 3.3 ! :D

Here's my computer:

- Core I5 with HD 3000 and GT 540M
- Kali Linux 1.0.9 updated
- Kernel 3.14 i686-pae with nvidia 331.67 kernel modules
- bumblebee-nvidia installed through wheezy-backports repository

My steps:

```
> # export CFLAGS="-m32"
> # export CXXFLAGS="-m32"
> # ./autogen.sh --enable-driglx-direct --enable-gles-overlay --enable-gles1 --enable-gles2 --enable-glx-tls --with-driver=dri --with-dri-driverdir=/usr/lib/dri --with-egl-platforms='drm x11' --with-state-trackers=egl,glx,dri,vega --with-dri-drivers=i965 --enable-32-bit --disable-64-bit --enable-gallium-llvm=disabled --enable-gallium-gbm=disabled --enable-gallium-egl=disabled --with-gallium-drivers= --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
> # ./configure --prefix=/usr
> # make
```

And the make bug report:

```
Making all in nouveau
make[6]: Entering directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa/drivers/dri/nouveau'
  CC     nouveau_screen.lo
In file included from nouveau_screen.c:27:0:
nouveau_driver.h:41:28: fatal error: libdrm/nouveau.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[6]: *** [nouveau_screen.lo] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa/drivers/dri/nouveau'
make[5]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa/drivers/dri'
make[4]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa/drivers'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src/mesa'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Data/Mesa-9.0.3/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

---

I gave up using Debian's libdrm implementation since it behaves differently than the official one's sources. Hence I still prefer using the previous way for Mesa 10.0.5 or newer since I won't have to compile a newer libdrm and keep more guaranteed stability.

I am facing now a new problem, the Mesa 10.0.5 I managed to compile -with libdrm 2.4.58- seems to not be in use while running glxheads since the it shows me:

```
GL_VERSION:  1.4 (2.1 Mesa 8.0.5)
```

Which is the Debian's stable own Mesa. I also found out that some people are also stuck on this problem: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&p=696973

The question is: how to correctly compile libdrm and Mesa from the sources with the correct flags, exports and packages installation/uninstallation ?

It would really help if a related Debian maintainer could answer.

Here's my steps:

Common, installed packages and their implied dependencies by using Synaptic:

```
checkinstall
automake
bison
flex
libdrm-dev
libx11-xcb-dev
libxcb-glx0-dev
libxcb-xfixes0-dev
llvm
x11proto-dri2-dev
x11proto-gl-dev
xutils-dev
pkg-config
libltdl-dev
libxdamage-dev
libexpat1-dev
libpciaccess-dev
gettext
```

Common, manually installed packages:

> https://packages.debian.org/jessie/x11proto-dri3-dev
>
> https://packages.debian.org/jessie/x11proto-present-dev

For libdrm, from this package: http://dri.freedesktop.org/libdrm/libdrm-2.4.58.tar.gz:

```
# ./configure
# make
# checkinstall
```

For Mesa, from this package: ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/older-versions/10.x/10.0.5/MesaLib-10.0.5.zip:

```
# ./autogen.sh
# make
# checkinstall

# aptitude install mesa-utils
then as standard user:
$ export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libGL.so.1
$ export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/lib/dri
$ glxheads
```

Here's the two followed guides:

> http://dri.freedesktop.org/wiki/Building/
>
> http://verahill.blogspot.fr/2012/11/mesa-901-64-bit-on-debian-wheezy.html

---

I managed to go further this time, and almost using for good Mesa 10.0.5.

Now my steps for the Mesa 10.0.5 sources are:

```
# autoreconf -vfi
# ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-driglx-direct --enable-gles1 --enable-gles2 --enable-glx-tls --with-dri-driverdir=/usr/lib/dri --with-egl-platforms='drm x11' --with-dri-drivers=i965
# make
# checkinstall
# export LIBGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib/dri
# export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
# export EGL_DRIVERS_PATH=/usr/lib
```

But the problem is that when I am using glxheads, it shows me that I am using Mesa 10.0.5, but that I only use OpenGL 2.1 instead of OpenGL 3.3.
Furthermore, it's still very slow on Team Fortress 2, and every textures have an ugly grain effect, but no more green texture on training video.

The question is: How can I correctly make OpenGL 3.3 available for Mesa 10.0.5 and avoid the ugly-grain texture problem ?

Before:

```
GL_VERSION:  3.0 Mesa 8.0.5
GL_VENDOR:   Tungsten Graphics, Inc
GL_RENDERER: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
```

Now:

```
GL_VERSION:  2.1 Mesa 10.0.5
GL_VENDOR:   VMware, Inc.
GL_RENDERER: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.0, 128 bits)
```

Despite the GL_VENDOR shows that it's VMware, I am doing everything bare-metal and not on a virtual machine.

Note that this time, I still naively compiled libdrm-2.4.58 like as said on the README file.  And then compiled Mesa 10.0.5 without x11proto-dri3-dev, x11-proto-present-dev and inxi now.

Here's the guide I used in order to compile Mesa and, so far the best one:
http://x.debian.net/howto/build-mesa.html

Comment: So what exactly is your question?  The compiler error seems pretty clear, you have a linker error.

Comment: The problem is that I can't really find the nouveau.h header with an updatedb + locate. The file does not even exists in the repositories packages.

So I think the guy have found a way to overcome that missing file problem but how ?

Comment: Which version of libdrm are you using?  Newer than 2.4.33 ?

Comment: Yup, mine's 2.4.40.

Comment: @Ramhound: "libdrm/nouveau.h: no such file or directory" <- not a linker error :)

Comment: @Ramhound: that's why it is an error at the compiling stage, not the linking stage.

Comment: Sure; fine; compiler error not linker error;

Comment: Please do not continuously edit your question with useless trivial edits. If someone knew then they would answer it. You could always try adding a bounty to try and get attention for your problem.

Comment: Over the internet at least four people already managed to do it. I mean, it's not that impossible to answer since it's just a mis-understood compilation problem.

The main problem is that these people didn't mention every steps they made to make it so, and contacting them is worthless since they didn't answer, even the Debian Mesa maintainer. :(

Comment: I get that it is a problem and that it should be fixable, but abusing this site in an attempt to garner some attention is not the way to go about fixing *anything*. If you have meaningful information to add then fine, but "bumping" your question in this manner is unacceptable and is risking getting your question closed. As I mentioned you could consider posting a bounty which would encourage some people to put in some effort for you.

Comment: Alternatively if you edit your question to clean it up we could potentially consider migrating it to [Unix.se] where it *may* possibly have a better audience. Before that though I would recommend you post a question on [their meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com) and if you got some support for a migration then we could move it for you. Do **not** simply repost this there.